# How to skip empty objects in query conditional fragment?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I have a query to return objects of type `ObjectA`. The response is using a conditional fragment.

```
union Objects = ObjectA | ObjectB | ObjectC

getObjects {
  ... on ObjectA {
    name
  }
}
```

The resolver will return all objects

```
$util.toJSON($ctx.result.objects)
```

However, I got a response:

```
[
  {
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "name": "airplane"
  },
  {},
  {}
]
```

The last two "empty" objects are not of type `ObjectA`.

My question is, is there a way using conditional fragment to exclude "empty" objects from different type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to automatically remove empty object from response.

You can always write some code to remove empty obj in the response object.

Comment: Right. That's what I have found out too upon checking graphql's way of doing [conditional fragment with unions](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types).

Comment: and 2 years later... so sad. 